# EF Core Only 3 of the 12 models were scaffolded

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm not sure what could be wrong, when I run the command

`Scaffold-DbContext "Server=TestServer;Database=CIR;Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models`

The operation completes successfully, the problem is, only 3 models are built. 3 of the tables are being imported, but not the remaining 9. The only thing I can think of, is that the 3 tables that had managed to be brought in, had PK's on them. Where as there is no need on the other ones, and so they weren't created. Is it true then that Entity framework requires there be Primary keys on every table to be converted to a model?

Answer (score 2):

Yes,  EF requires a primary key on each table, and having that is standard good practice